# I am converting custom php of magento 1 into magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

this is the error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Area code is not set in /var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:152 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(173): Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode() #1 /var/www/html/magento22/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() #2 /var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(130): Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start() #3 /var/www/html/magento22/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Validator), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Storage), Object(Magento\Framewor in /var/www/html/magento22/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 175
```

this is the code .I am converting  Mage::getModel('sales/order'); in magento 2

```
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orders = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
```

how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. 
I found solution so want to share it.
Add this line

```
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');
```

before

```
$orders = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert `Mage::getModel('sales/order');` in `magento2` you can use following code

```
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orders = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
```

Comment: NO this is not working I am fetching data by order id so no problem with getCollection().